# Authentication Mechanisms in Terminal Servers

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, terminal-services, vdi

I am working on a legacy application wherein I have to implement authentication mechanism in VDI & Terminal Servers using Azure AD for different types of users (guest, member).

I could not find any resources on Azure blogs regarding AAD B2B for VDI and Terminal Servers.

Is there any tutorial on approach or technique that could be helpful?